# Pipeline creation on AWS with GitHub repository

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, pipeline, awsdeploy

When we create a pipeline on AWS we can provide a Github repo, let's say the repo name is: **"RepoName/exampleProject"** and in this repo, we have many folders. So can we provide a subfolder from this repo like **"RepoName/exampleProject/subFolder"** to repo section in add source stage in AWS?

Since we could have two Folders in this repo like Laravel for the backend and a separate project Vue Js for the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not for GitHub or AWS CodeCommit. Basically, its a no for any git provider.
What your are providing here is a / and the you provide branch.

These details are required to git clone the source code which will be transition to next stage. When you do a git clone, you clone the entire repository and not any specific folder.

If your source files are on S3, it will be a different case. S3 is not a git based version control. You can download specific folder from S3.

Comment: so is there any other way to do that without uploading your code to S3?

Comment: It depends on how your code is organized and how you build/deploy it. You can move frontend code into another repo altogether, or can use existing CodePipeline and just ignore frontend (or backend) while build/deploying respective services.